# Exception to overwrite

Tags: vbscript

I have a VBScript - if I run it I do not want it repeating the words it is replacing. Is there an `If` statement I can add to stop it doing this?

```
Option Explicit
Const ForReading = 1
Const ForWriting = 2
Dim objFSO,objFile,strText,strNewText
Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set objFile = objFSO.OpenTextFile("C:\Users\newtons\Desktop\Text.txt",ForReading)

strText = objFile.ReadAll
objFile.Close
strNewText = Replace(strText, "<Jim","<!--<Jim")

'<pseudocode>
IF "<!--<Jim" = EXIST THEN DO NOTHING
END IF
'</pseudocode>

Set objFile = objFSO.OpenTextFile("C:\Users\newtons\Desktop\Text.txt",ForWriting)
objFile.WriteLine strNewText
objFile.Close
set objFSO = Nothing
set objFile =
```

Comment: Can you clarify the "repeating" part? You're reading the text from a file into a variable, replacing all instances of "Jim" with "James" in that variable, then replacing the text in the file with the text from the variable. Where's the problem?

Comment: Please see my edit if I run the script x2 = <!--<Jim<!--<Jim

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace `<Jim` with `<!--Jim` instead of `<!--<Jim` to avoid repeated replacements (i.e. make sure that your search string isn't a substring of your replacement string).

Comment: I need <!--< adding into the text file but I understand why - the script is finding the first < then the last <

Answer (score 1):

You can use [InStr()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wybb344c%28v=vs.84%29.aspx) to check whether `strText` contains "Jim" or "James" and do or don't replace or save according to what you really want to achieve.

The docs for `Replace()` explain how to restrict the number of substitutions - if that's what your "execption"/"repeating" is hinting at.

Demo:

```
>> WScript.Echo Replace("AA", "A", "a", 1, 1, vbTextCompare)
>>
aA
>>
```